# had to have been vs. has to have been vs. must have been

Tags: have-to-versus-must

At 4:18 of this video titled "[Trump's UN Speech Advocates For Both Peace And Nuclear War](https://youtu.be/nmwDV_DOlFg?t=4m18s)", Stephen Colbert said:

> *Now, the most awkward moment **had to have been** when he brought up Venezuela.*

And then he showed a clip of Trump's "most awkward moment" at his UN speech.

I wonder if it has to be ***had to have been*** instead of ***has to have been*** or ***must have been***.

I'm pretty much sure that you can easily use ***must have been*** there without any problem. But I'm not quite sure why Stephen used ***had to have been*** instead of ***has to have been*** in this context.

Comment: It didn’t have to have been *had to have been* since *must have been* and even *has to have been* would have been ok.

Answer (score 1):

The speaker is speculating about something **in the past** (so basically it is a past modal here, meaning *has to have been* is irrelevant) and there is different degrees to speculation indeed. *Had to have been* is stronger than *must have been* and *might/may/could have been* is the weakest of all. *Must have done* means *it's almost certain that something was the case* while *had to have done* means *it's very certain that something was the case*.

Comment: Q. asked about "must have been": you've commented on "must have done".  Was that intentional or an error.

Comment: @TrevorD By _must have done_, I meant to generalize, a past participle, including _been_.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because 'must have been' already has another meaning, i.e. the deductive one.

e.g: Who took the car? It must have been Paul because Jim's still here.

So to say that moment 'must have been' the most awkward would suggest that Stephen Colbert wasn't completely sure, that he was making a deduction based on less than all of the facts.

'had to have been', on the other hand, has a persuasive feel - not that the speaker is unsure but that he wants to convince his audience. This, I believe, is the same difference in feel as between:

I must lose weight - I personally feel this is necessary, internal motivation

and

I have to lose weight - an outside authority or need says so, external motivation.

(For difference between 'must' and 'have to', see Murphy English Grammar in Use, CUP 2012 or Swan, Practical English Usage)

Comment: If you would like to draw on external sources for corroboration, please quote the relevant passages here. (You only need to quote what's absolutely necessary, it's not supposed to be an onerous requirement.)